# UITabBarController's view controller overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, overlap

My App has one tab bar containing 4 view controllers. 3 view controllers are programmed through `xib` and I started with `Storyboard` for 4th view controller, added to tab bar controller as usual.

Sometimes, when I am navigating between these view controllera, two view controllers will overlap. I saw this in view debugging also.

Sample code below.

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

//1st view controller
GeneralViewController *infoView = [[GeneralViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeneralViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *infoTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoView];
[infoTab.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Activity"];

//2nd view controller
SupportTabViewController *supportViewCont = [[SupportTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *supportTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:supportViewCont];
[supportTab.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Support"];

//3rd view controller
MessageViewController *messageTab = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *MessageNavTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:messageTab];
[messageTab.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Message"];

//4th view controller
SurveyDefaultViewController *surveyDefaultViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"survey" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SurveyDefaultViewController"];

UINavigationController *surveyNavTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:surveyDefaultViewController];
[surveyNavTab.tabBarItem setTitle:@"TV Survey"];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoTab,supportTab,MessageNavTab,surveyNavTab, nil]];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code for this? And maybe screenshots so that we can understand what you mean by overlap.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to upload image. so i hav uploaded to dropbox and sharing link here . https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzdhj3xt2qbzbzx/neww.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You should also edit your question to provide some code.

Comment: yes. added sample code.